# STM32F103 - CubeMx - MCU reboots with FreeRtos v9

Tags: stm32f10x, stm32cubemx, freertos

I using a STM32F103 in my project and I generate the Keil project with Cube32MX with this firmware package for STM32F1 version 1.4.0.

Today I update the Cube to version 4.23.0 and I migrate my project (including the update to the firmware package v 1.6.0.

There is no problem during the program compile, unless some Watchdog defines. I use FreeRtos v. 9 but previously ( when everything works I use v. 8)

When I run the program in debug mode the peripheral initialisation (main.c) works, but when the my task starts the program restart and execute again the peripheral initialisation into the main.c file.

```
#if ( ( configUSE_PREEMPTION == 1 ) && ( configIDLE_SHOULD_YIELD == 1 ) )
{
   /* When using preemption tasks of equal priority will be
   timesliced. If a task that is sharing the idle priority is ready
   to run then the idle task should yield before the end of the
   timeslice.
   A critical region is not required here as we are just reading from
   the list, and an occasional incorrect value will not matter. If
   the ready list at the idle priority contains more than one task
   then a task other than the idle task is ready to execute. */
   if( listCURRENT_LIST_LENGTH( &( pxReadyTasksLists[ tskIDLE_PRIORITY ] ) ) > ( UBaseType_t ) 1 )
   {
     taskYIELD();
   }
   else
   {
     mtCOVERAGE_TEST_MARKER();
   }
}
```

I try to disable the FreeRtos preemption, I tried to change the system timer but nothing has changed.

Should I modify some FreeRtos configuration parameters into Cube32Mx?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could it be a watchdog issue? Are you single stepping through to find out what is happening and exactly where it jumps back to?

Comment: BTW, there is a non-cube version of FreeRTOS for the F103, you would be *much* better off using that. Cube is just a messy bloatfest.

Comment: @DiBosco: I cannot because the configuration of peripherals is built with cube and shared with several person. Now I check the watchdog

Comment: I disabled the watchdog but nothing has changed. The MCU reboots. I have not other ideas.

Comment: I fail to see how sharing peripherals means you have to use Cube. In terms of other ideas, you haven't answered my question about single stepping through the code until it reboots/resets.

Comment: Sorry, I can single step during the peripheral initialisation into the main.c. But when the task is started if it try to go away with single step the execution jump to the above code snippet.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry too, I misunderstood what you meant.  Is there a particular instruction where this happens? Can you bury down into the disassembly to say at the exact point it occurs? I'm really not clear at the precise point this is falling over. You might be best posting on the excellent FreeRTOS forum on Sourceforge and including as much detail as possible. 

When I've had similar-ish FreeRTOS problems I've ended up single stepping through the assembly code before eventually understanding what was going on.

Comment: @DiBosco thanks for the into! I'll looking into the disassembly code and I'll post an update